# How does the researcher deal with new data different of what they have learned?

Tags: research-process, research-tools, research-design

I am currently studying the book Alberts 5 edition 2016. I was wondering how much of the info will remaining vigent in 10 years.
How does the researcher deal with this kind of things? Do they have to relearn, every new edition of every book that they have learned related to his work?

Comment: Life is their book.

Comment: Papers.... type a topic of interest: [Pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/)

Comment: Most of what makes it into a textbook is fairly settled knowledge; there are always minor exceptions being found to whatever rule you think you're sure of in biology (we're not physics), but paradigm shifts make news at scale appropriate to their disruption.